# Data push using akka scheduler

Tags: scala, akka

I am looking for some example on akka scheduler usage. I have one actor (lets call it - dataProducer) implementation for retrieving data from some database. I would like to write one scheduler actor which will pole the dataProducer actor in 5 seconds interval. Also how to handle the case if data retrieval takes more time than scheduler interval. Will scheduleOnce method in Scheduler actor handle this?

Here is my scheduler actor

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, TimeUnit}
import akka.actor.{Actor, Cancellable, Props}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class SchedulerActor(interval: Long) extends Actor with LogF{

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))

  private var scheduler: Cancellable = _

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    scheduler = context.system.scheduler.schedule(
      initialDelay = 0 seconds,
      interval = FiniteDuration(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
      receiver = self,
      message = FetchData
    )
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    scheduler.cancel()
  }

  def receive = {
    case FetchData =>
      logger.debug( "Fetch Data" )
      sender() ! "Data Fetched!!!" //here I'll call dataProducer API
      true
    case unknown =>
      throw new RuntimeException( "ERROR: Received unknown message [" + unknown + "], can't handle it" )
  }

}

object SchedulerActor {

  def props(interval: Long): Props = Props(new SchedulerActor(interval))
}

sealed trait FetchDataMessage
case object FetchData extends FetchDataMessage
```

Comment: If you want to get meaningful answers, I'd suggest you showing what you tried so far.

Comment: Updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler's `scheduleOnce` helps to execute a piece of after some delay.
Have different states and switch between states to accept different kind of messages and act accordingly. But when timeout happens scheduleOnce will take you to timeoutState.

ScheduleOnce will help the actor know that timeout has happened.

> how to handle the case if data retrieval takes more time than scheduler interval ?

If data fetch takes more than specified time actor state changes `timeoutState` and in the timeout state say what should be done to the actor. Either you can retry or try different source.

> I would like to write one scheduler actor which will pole the dataProducer actor in 5 seconds interval

In the result state wait for scheduleOnce with 5 seconds delay to request the dataProducer and whole thing repeats again.

Check this code to understand how it can be done.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Cancellable}
import stackoverflow.DBUtils.Entity

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.pipe


object DBPollActor {
  case class Result(results: List[Entity])
  case object Schedule
  case object Timeup
  case object FetchData
}

object DBUtils {
  case class Entity(name: String)

  def doDBOperation: Future[List[Entity]] = {
    Future.successful(List(Entity(name = "foo")))
  }

}

class DBPollActor(timeout: Int) extends Actor {

  import DBPollActor._

  implicit val ex = context.system.dispatcher

  var schedulerOpt: Option[Cancellable] = None

  @scala.throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    self ! FetchData
    schedulerOpt = Some(context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeout seconds) {
      context become timeoutState
      self ! Timeup
    })
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg@FetchData =>
      context become startState
      self forward msg
  }

  def startState: Receive = {
    case FetchData =>
      schedulerOpt.map(_.cancel())
      context become resultState
      DBUtils.doDBOperation.map(Result) pipeTo self
      schedulerOpt = Some(context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeout seconds) {
        context become timeoutState
        self ! Timeup
      })
  }

  def timeoutState: Receive = {
    case Timeup =>
      schedulerOpt.map(_.cancel())
      //Timeout happened do something or repeat
  }

  def resultState:  Receive = {
    case result@Result(list) =>
      schedulerOpt.map(_.cancel())
      //Result available consume the result and repeat or doSomething different
     context become resultState
      DBUtils.doDBOperation.map(Result) pipeTo self
      schedulerOpt = Some(context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeout seconds) {
        context become timeoutState
        self ! Timeup
      })

    case ex: Exception =>
      schedulerOpt.map(_.cancel())
      //future failed exit or retry
  }
}
```